# What happens to the light bulb?

Tags: power-supply

What happens to the light bulbs if the power switch is connected. Will B shine brighter or will both? Or will nothing happen?

A & B are light bulbs.

[image: A & B are light bulbs]

Comment: Is this a homework?  If so, what were you able to figure out so far?

Comment: I know that the bulbs light depends on the current and that the light in serrial will shine less than if they would be parralel because of parralel making the total resistan smaler than in serial. 
What my thought are is is that the bulds will shine brighter but I do not know if both will or just one.
My answer right now would be that B will shine brighter.

Comment: Let's assume that both light bulbs have the same resistance at all times, also all 3 batteries are identical and each produces the voltage V_batt.  Then what's the voltage (potential) of the point between the light bulbs?  What's the potential at the point between the two batteries on the right hand side?  (Keep in mind that batteries are ideal voltage sources, not ideal current sources for the purposes of this discussion.)

Comment: The right hand side should be 2V. And correct me if im wrong but in between the bulbs the voltage will be halved, so 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that all your batteries are of same voltage and are able to deliver arbitrary currents. Additionally I'm assuming the bulbs have equal inner resistance.

A and B divide the voltage exactly in half. So the potential on both terminals of the switch is the same in opened state. In this case closing it would have no effect at all.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE.  For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment.  We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when the O.P. had demonstrated sufficient effort of his own.  Otherwise, we would be doing the O.P. a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time.  See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Comment: @NickAlexeev Sorry. I wasn't aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

In a circuit that's driven by voltage sources, (i.e., almost all circuits), in this case the batteries, you have to look first at the voltages throughout. Figure out what the voltage is across each light bulb when the switch is open, and from that, figure out the current through each bulb. Then do the same thing with the switch closed.